# How can I create a data.frame in R of how many times players start together in games

Tags: r, purrr

I am just starting looking at network analysis and wanted to begin by creating a data.frame of how often basketball players on a team have started together

Ideally, I would like to incorporate map functions from `purrr`

So with this as input

```
game_1 <- c("Andy","Bob","Chris","Doug","Evan") 
game_2 <- c("Andy","Chris","Evan","Fred","George")
```

I would want a result like this

```
n_1  n_2 games

Andy  Bob    1
Andy  Chris  2
Andy  Doug   1
Andy  Evan   2
Andy  Fred   1
Andy  George 1
Bob   Chris  1
Bob   Doug   1
Bob   Evan   1
Chris Doug   1
Chris Evan   2
Chris Fred   1
Chris George 1
Doug  Evan   1
Evan  Fred   1
Evan  George 1
Fred  George 1
```

Comment: `expand.grid(game_1,game_2)` could be a potential starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution does not use `purrr`, but it should work

```
game_1 <- c("Andy","Bob","Chris","Doug","Evan") 
game_2 <- c("Andy","Chris","Evan","Fred","George")

# Combine all games into a single list for use with lapply
all_games <- list(game_1, game_2)

library(dplyr)

# Find combinations, sorted to ensure the earlier alphabets are in the first column
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all_games, function(x) { data.frame(t(combn(sort(x), 2)))  })) 

# Calculate the number of instances where 2 players appear with each other
df %>% group_by(X1, X2) %>% summarise(count = n())
# A tibble: 17 x 3
# Groups:   X1 [?]
# X1     X2 count
# <fctr> <fctr> <int>
#   1   Andy    Bob     1
# 2   Andy  Chris     2
# 3   Andy   Doug     1
# 4   Andy   Evan     2
# 5   Andy   Fred     1
# 6   Andy George     1
# 7    Bob  Chris     1
# 8    Bob   Doug     1
# 9    Bob   Evan     1
# 10  Chris   Doug     1
# 11  Chris   Evan     2
# 12  Chris   Fred     1
# 13  Chris George     1
# 14   Doug   Evan     1
# 15   Evan   Fred     1
# 16   Evan George     1
# 17   Fred George     1
```

Comment: @whalea Thanks for quick response. That actually has duplicates e.g Andy Bob & Bob Andy both appear. Is there a quick adaptation to cater for that

Comment: @pssguy thanks for pointing out the duplicates, I have changed the function inside `lapply` to use `combn` instead which should solve the problem. Note the importance of using `sort` for this method to work

Comment: @whalea. Looks good. I can prob adapt further if I want to. Used it for real life situation and  only took 15secs for 1000 games of soccer lineups (so 11 rather than 5)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

# get combinations from game_1
g1 <- combn(game_1, 2) %>% t 

# get combinations from game_2
g2 <- combn(game_2, 2) %>% t 

# bind both in a dataframe and count pairs
g1 %>% 
  rbind.data.frame(g2) %>% 
  group_by(V1, V2) %>% 
  summarise(games = n())

# A tibble: 17 x 3
# Groups:   V1 [?]
       V1     V2 games
   <fctr> <fctr> <int>
 1   Andy    Bob     1
 2   Andy  Chris     2
 3   Andy   Doug     1
 4   Andy   Evan     2
 5   Andy   Fred     1
 6   Andy George     1
 7    Bob  Chris     1
 8    Bob   Doug     1
 9    Bob   Evan     1
10  Chris   Doug     1
11  Chris   Evan     2
12  Chris   Fred     1
13  Chris George     1
14   Doug   Evan     1
15   Evan   Fred     1
16   Evan George     1
17   Fred George     1
```

Answer (score 0):

building on whalea's answer:

```
game_1 <- c("Andy","Bob","Chris","Doug","Evan") 
game_2 <- c("Andy","Chris","Evan","Fred","George")

all_games <- list(game_1, game_2)

library(dplyr)
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all_games, function(x) { expand.grid(x, x) %>% filter(Var1 != Var2) })) %>% apply(1,sort) %>% t %>% data.frame
df %>% group_by(X1, X2) %>% summarise(count = n()/2)
```

result:

```
 1 Andy  Bob       1.
 2 Andy  Chris     2.
 3 Andy  Doug      1.
 4 Andy  Evan      2.
 5 Andy  Fred      1.
 6 Andy  George    1.
 7 Bob   Chris     1.
 8 Bob   Doug      1.
 9 Bob   Evan      1.
10 Chris Doug      1.
11 Chris Evan      2.
12 Chris Fred      1.
13 Chris George    1.
14 Doug  Evan      1.
15 Evan  Fred      1.
16 Evan  George    1.
17 Fred  George    1.
```